# Google Sheets - Create New Sheets in New Spreadsheet from Column of Unknown Length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm new to JavaScript and I want to do a little automation for work and wondering if I could get some help.  Spreadsheet A is a template that can have an unknown number of cells with data in Column B starting at B2.  When I click on my add-on menu button that I've created, a new spreadsheet (Spreadsheet B) is created but then I want to populate new sheets with titles based on the data in Column B from Spreadsheet A into Spreadsheet B

I understand that this will have to be placed within a While loop but working with spreadsheets is causing me a little confusion.

Thanks!

*Copy these Cells from Spreadsheet A:*

[image: Copy these Cells from Spreadsheet A]

*Create new sheets based on Spreadsheet A cells in Spreadsheet B:*

[image: Create new sheets based on Spreadsheet A cells in Spreadsheet B]

So far, this is what I have:

```
function pickListCreation(){
  //This line creates Spreadsheet B (New Pick List)
  var newPickList = SpreadsheetApp.create("New Pick List");
       Logger.log(newPickList.getUrl());
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //Data in Column B from Spreadsheet A will be Room Numbers.  Room Number variable declared
  var roomNumber = activeSheet.getRange(2,2);
  //While loop that will run as long as there is data in the cell of Column B in Spreadsheet A
  while (roomNumber.isBlank() !== false){
  //Variable newPickSheet that is set to the value of the current cell  
    var newPickSheet = roomNumber.getValue();
  //Insert new sheet with newPickSheet as the title in newPickList (Spreadsheet B)
    newPickList.insertSheet(newPickSheet);
  //Move down one cell in the column
    roomNumber = activeSheet.getRange(i+1, 2);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the script you wrote so far?

Comment: Also, you need to improve your question.  Here is a reference on how to write a good question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited my post.  Sorry for all the comments but I wanted to try and be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Where was `i` declared? You might want to spend some time learning how to write [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

Comment: Thanks Cooper, totally forgot to do that.  I got the basics of how to write a for loop but I figured since Column B will be of an undetermined length based on what the user is working on, a while loop would be better to run until there is a blank row in the column notating the end.  However, if there is an easier way, I'm open to it.

Comment: You can determine the last row of data in a sheet. Read the Apps Script Documentation,

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would create new sheets from data in Sheet1:

```
function addSheets() {
    var curTabNameArray = [];
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var theRowCount = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getDataRange().getNumRows();
    var myRange = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2, 2, theRowCount - 1); // we start on 2nd row
    var newProposedSheetNamesArray = myRange.getValues();

    var oldTabsObjArray = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
    var oldTabsCount = oldTabsObjArray.length;

    for (var a = 0; a < oldTabsCount; a++) { // push names of old existing sheets into array
        curTabNameArray.push(oldTabsObjArray[a].getName());
    }

    for (var myCounter = 0; myCounter < theRowCount - 1; myCounter++) {
        var curProposedNewSheetName = newProposedSheetNamesArray[myCounter];
        var curProposedNewSheetNameString = curProposedNewSheetName[0];
        var newIndex = curTabNameArray.indexOf(curProposedNewSheetNameString);
        if (newIndex > -1) {
            Logger.log("curProposedNewSheetName already exists");
        } else {
            Logger.log("adding sheet " + curProposedNewSheetNameString);
            activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(curProposedNewSheetNameString, activeSpreadsheet.getSheets().length);
        }
    }
}
```